# Zend Framework: when do session io operations really occur?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

When using session and namespaces, when do IO operations really occur (since sessions are stored as files somewhere on the server)?

As soon as I declare a new instance of *Zend_Session_Namespace*?

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace');
```

As soon as I read or write into a variable of the namespace?

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace');
$myNamespace->someVar = 3;
$myVar = $myNamespace->someVar;
```

I would like to know which operation is really expensive (IO read/write).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Session_Namespace` uses native PHP sessions.
According the official PHP documentation:

> When PHP shuts down (or when `session_write_close()` is called), PHP will internally encode the `$_SESSION` superglobal and pass this along with the session ID to the the write callback. After the write callback has finished, PHP will internally invoke the close callback handler.

As you can read, the session is written when the script shuts down.

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Session_Namespace act as a wrapper to $_SESSION .

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace'); //write operation $_SESSION
$myNamespace->someVar = 3;               //write operation on $_SESSION
$myVar = $myNamespace->someVar;                // read operation on $_SESSION
```

but in all the cases read/write IO took place on RAM not on hardisk . When your application instance end's then only it gets written on hardisk.